# connect to internet if users like my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

I am building a guest wireless access for a pub. The idea is that users will be granted with internet access if they like they pub's website.
Now I was checking the requirements on facebook to check this and I found [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.5#reference-user_likes):

> Gate access to your app, or some content within your app based on
>   whether or not someone has liked a page.

**NOTE:** [facebook wifi](https://www.facebook.com/help/109150235937957) is not a solution for me hence I am using ubiquiti unifi AP

Does it means that I can't read if my clients like my page in order to allow them to use my wifi? is there a way around it?

Comment: Don’t re-invent the wheel. https://www.facebook.com/business/facebook-wifi, https://www.facebook.com/help/126760650808045/

Comment: @CBroe unfortunately I am using unifi which is not compatible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's the solely purpose of the `user_likes` permission for your app you will very likely not pass the Login Review process.

Comment: Well, if it's not allowed, you can't use this feature. That's what I'd recommend :-/